# Is it bad practice to have an empty intermediary class in a class Hierarchy?

Tags: java, class, polymorphism

I am writing a dense hierarchy of classes all deriving from a single abstract parent class for a project that will need to make use of polymorphism, and also to trace objects through the class hierarchy. I have determined that a cluster of classes are the same, in that they could all have an abstract parent class which is a child of the overall parent. However, for the purposes of the project, there is no need to implement anything in this class that isn't already defined in its parent. I have decided to create the class and leave it empty, as I feel it would be useful in narrowing down precisely what kind of object the program is dealing with at run time. Is this bad practice?

Comment: According to it's help page, this is a question best asked on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If there is nothing to distinguish the "child" class from its "parent", I would not recommend creating that class. If there is a differentiation ..then it should express itself through some change in behavior or additional behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In certain cases, this is fully acceptable. I've done this before; it mostly involved empty classes which would specify certain generic parameters, so they were not "really" empty, as the type parameters narrowed the base class down a bit.

Comment: Now that I think about it a bit more, I could add a few distinguishing parameters to it.